# Flip fancyhdr headrule even odd

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to achieve a short fading `\headrule` under page numbers. But I cannot figure out how to "flip" it on even/odd pages. Does anyone know how to manage that?

I also get a warning saying that the `headheight` is too small. This is caused by the `tikzpicture`, but how can I fix it? I don't want to increase the `headheight` by that much...

```
\documentclass[11pt, titlepage, openright]{book}

\usepackage[textwidth=13cm, left=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, top=2.5cm, paperwidth=20cm, paperheight=27cm, layoutwidth=19cm, layoutheight=26cm, layouthoffset=0.5cm, layoutvoffset=0.5cm, showcrop, asymmetric]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}

\definecolor{grey}{rgb}{0.6,0.6,0.6}
\definecolor{darkgrey}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}

\setlength{\headheight}{24pt}
\fancyhead[RO]{\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{grey}\leftmark\hspace{0.3cm}\sffamily\textcolor{darkgrey}\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{darkgrey}\thepage\hspace{0.3cm}\sffamily\textcolor{grey}\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.6pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \shade[white] (0,0) rectangle (8,0);
    \shade[left color=white, right color=black, dashed] (8,1) rectangle (12.98,1.01);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: headrule doesn't have left and right options as far as I know but you can add it to lhead and rhead. Then it is much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In standard LaTeX the check for left/right headers is performed on the value of `\count0` via `\ifodd`.  You can use this in your `\headrule` command to set different pictures on the two pages.

Adding a `headheight` option to your `geometry` specification will give more space.  Use the value reported in the log file.

However, you say in your question you don't want to do that.  The reason your header is so tall is that you try to move it up by draw something blank at height `0` and the rule at height `1`.  Easier is to just draw the rule and make sure that it is positioned correctly by using some vertical skips.

[image: Sample even page]

[image: Sample odd page]

```
\documentclass[11pt, titlepage, openright]{book}

\usepackage[textwidth=13cm, left=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, top=2.5cm,
paperwidth=20cm, paperheight=27cm, layoutwidth=19cm,
layoutheight=26cm, layouthoffset=0.5cm, layoutvoffset=0.5cm,
showcrop, asymmetric]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}

\definecolor{grey}{rgb}{0.6,0.6,0.6}
\definecolor{darkgrey}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}

\setlength{\headheight}{24pt}
\fancyhead[RO]{\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{grey}\leftmark\hspace{0.3cm}\sffamily\textcolor{darkgrey}\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{darkgrey}\thepage\hspace{0.3cm}\sffamily\textcolor{grey}\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.6pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\headrule}{%
\vskip-\baselineskip\vskip4pt
\ifodd\count0\hfill\begin{tikzpicture}
    \shade[left color=white, right color=black, dashed] (0,0) rectangle (4.98,0.01);
\end{tikzpicture}\else\begin{tikzpicture}
    \shade[left color=black, right color=white, dashed] (0,0) rectangle (4.98,.01);
\end{tikzpicture}\fi}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with the `etoolbox` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt, titlepage, openright]{book}

\usepackage[textwidth=13cm, left=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, top=2.5cm, paperwidth=20cm, paperheight=27cm, layoutwidth=19cm, layoutheight=26cm, layouthoffset=0.5cm, layoutvoffset=0.5cm, showcrop, asymmetric]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}

\definecolor{grey}{rgb}{0.6,0.6,0.6}
\definecolor{darkgrey}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\setlength{\headheight}{24pt}
\fancyhead[RO]{\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{grey}\leftmark\hspace{0.3cm}\sffamily\textcolor{darkgrey}\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{darkgrey}\thepage\hspace{0.3cm}\sffamily\textcolor{grey}\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.6pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\headrule}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\ifnumodd{\value{page}}{%
 \shade[white] (0,0) rectangle (8,0);
    \shade[left color=white, right color=black, dashed] (8,1) rectangle (12.98,1.01);
}%
{%
 \shade[white] (0,0) rectangle (5,0);
 \shade[left color=black, right color=white, dashed] (0,1) rectangle (4.98,1.02);
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
}%

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can put your `\fancyhead` contents inside a `node` and then drawing becomes easy.

```
\fancyhead[RO]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner xsep=0pt, align=right,text width=5cm] (a) {\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{grey}
             {\leftmark}\hspace{0.3cm}\sffamily\textcolor{darkgrey}{\thepage}};
    \shade[left color=white, right color=black, dashed] (a.south west) rectangle
            ([yshift=0.01cm]a.south east);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\fancyhead[LE]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner xsep=0pt, align=left,text width=5cm](a){\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{darkgrey}
     {\thepage}\hspace{0.3cm}\sffamily\textcolor{grey}{\leftmark}};
    \shade[right color=white, left color=black, dashed] (a.south west) rectangle
            ([yshift=0.01cm]a.south east);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, titlepage, openright]{book}

\usepackage[textwidth=13cm, left=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, top=2.5cm, paperwidth=20cm, paperheight=27cm, layoutwidth=19cm, layoutheight=26cm, layouthoffset=0.5cm, layoutvoffset=0.5cm, showcrop, asymmetric,headheight=24pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}

\definecolor{grey}{rgb}{0.6,0.6,0.6}
\definecolor{darkgrey}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}

%\setlength{\headheight}{24pt}
\fancyhead[RO]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner xsep=0pt, align=right,text width=5cm] (a) {\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{grey}
             {\leftmark}\hspace{0.3cm}\sffamily\textcolor{darkgrey}{\thepage}};
    \shade[left color=white, right color=black, dashed] (a.south west) rectangle
            ([yshift=0.01cm]a.south east);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\fancyhead[LE]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner xsep=0pt, align=left,text width=5cm](a){\sffamily\bfseries\textcolor{darkgrey}
     {\thepage}\hspace{0.3cm}\sffamily\textcolor{grey}{\leftmark}};
    \shade[right color=white, left color=black, dashed] (a.south west) rectangle
            ([yshift=0.01cm]a.south east);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! But how can I deal with longer chapter names? If I always want the faded line to be the same length..? At present the longer chapter names wrap into two lines, but I want them in one.

Comment: The reply from Andrew Swann fixed this.

Comment: @LarsNersveen That's easy. Use a fixed length like `\shade[left color=white, right color=black, dashed] (a.south east) rectangle
            +(5cm,0.01);`